# So much tragedy, so much suffering - WHY?

Tags: suffering

I am reading about Rabbi Haninah ben Teradion being burned alive, with wet wool stuffed into his body to prolong suffering by the Romans, the deaths of 24,000 students of Rabbi Akiva, the Destruction of Jerusalem and the Temple, Inquisitions, Pogroms, Holocaust, Intifadot, murders, burnings, sufferings, plagues - WHY? Can someone please tell me if this is to teach the Jews a lesson? Is this to punish them? How can this type of trauma not be transferred generationally to this generation and the psyche of so many? Where is the understanding of this magnitude of pain written? Why this extent? Is this a test of faith?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27875/purpose-of-suffering/99907#99907

Comment: Holocaust here - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8855/why-did-g-d-not-stop-the-holocaust

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/863/bad-things-happening-to-good-people/25575#25575